# Android custom view onVisibilityChanged call when activity resume

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i create a custom layout for auto - animation when it visible or gone.
Here my code:

```
public class DidiRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
private AnimUtils animUtils;
private int animVisible, animGone, durVisible, durGone;
public DidiRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    animUtils = AnimUtils.getInstance(context);
}

public DidiRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    animUtils = AnimUtils.getInstance(context);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout, 0, 0);
    try {
        animVisible = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_visible, -1);
        animGone = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_gone, -1);
        durVisible = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_visible_duration, AttributeConst.DEFAULT_DURATION_ANIMATION);
        durGone = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_gone_duration, AttributeConst.DEFAULT_DURATION_ANIMATION);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }
}

public DidiRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    animUtils = AnimUtils.getInstance(context);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout, defStyleAttr, 0);
    try {
        animVisible = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_visible, -1);
        animGone = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_gone, -1);
        durVisible = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_visible_duration, AttributeConst.DEFAULT_DURATION_ANIMATION);
        durGone = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.DidiRelativeLayout_anim_gone_duration, AttributeConst.DEFAULT_DURATION_ANIMATION);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(@NonNull View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    try {
        switch (visibility) {
            case VISIBLE:
                startAnimation(getAnim(animVisible, durVisible));
                break;
            case INVISIBLE:
            case GONE:
                startAnimation(getAnim(animGone, durGone));
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It work fine, but when activity resume from some where, onVisibilityChanged auto-call. How can i avoid it? Thanks.

Update: full code of custom layout

Comment: put your custom layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is because onResume is called when your activity is visible again so you could create a custom method and call when you want, replace this :

```
@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(@NonNull View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    try {
        switch (visibility) {
            case VISIBLE:
                startAnimation(getAnim(animVisible, durVisible));
                break;
            case INVISIBLE:
            case GONE:
                startAnimation(getAnim(animGone, durGone));
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public void changeVisibility(int visibility) {
try {
    switch (visibility) {
        case VISIBLE:
            startAnimation(getAnim(animVisible, durVisible));
            break;
        case INVISIBLE:
        case GONE:
            startAnimation(getAnim(animGone, durGone));
            break;
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

And call form your code:

```
yourView.changeVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I think you miss setVisibility(visibility); in function changeVisibility. Add it and work like a charm, thank you, dude